# PDO returns wrong value for select statement

Tags: php, mysql, select, pdo, rows

I've a PHP application that works with MySQL through PDO. I have a table with different records and I have to prevenet inserting a duplicate one. But when I want to check existing items, `select` statement does not return a true value. This is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_product_category1 WHERE title = '?'";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
if ($q->fetchColumn() == 0)
{
    ...
```

I also tested this one:

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM tbl_product_category1 WHERE title = '?'";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title));
$rows = $q->rowCount();
if ($rows == 0)
{
    ...
```

Imagine `$title=1`. I have 4 records with this value. But I can not see anything in `SELECT` statement. What is wrong here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: (*don't wrap the value of the title with single quotes*)

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tbl_product_category1 WHERE title = ? ";
```

Comment: your welcome mate. don't forget to accept if you think this is really the answer so others can also benefit :)